# CMS or Customised code

Tags: jsp, user-interface

I was looking for CMS similar application to embed my application. 
current situation

a. We have an application which can send alerts, create notifications and reports

b. Currently all the information is loaded manually by backend SQL (by change requests)

c. We are using JSP with hardcoded credentials to capture and input into DB

Requirements

1. To have an integrated webpage and manage the data entry via UI
2. The UI should have Login and session facilities, Web compatiblity and supported by modern browsers etc..
3. Within the UI, we should be able to create forms and data capture applications
4. User should be able to see the forms and enter data which we can then capture into the database

I'm not sure what software is required for this. I can't call it a CMS , but it should be similar to a "full fledged google form" or *surveymonkey* kind of application which we should be able to deploy into an application server.

Could you please recommend any such software packages?

Answer (score 0):

Well basically you want a dynamic UI, who's dynamics is not pertinent to a generic pattern, I.E your UI's structure (forms) can change to whatever. I think you're on the right track on using a Content Management System to store your various dynamic UI elements as (schemaless) documents. A better idea yet might be to use a schemaless database, such as Mongo db. The various CMSs that exist out there will usually give you more options than you need here, and thus more overhead and less performance. Mongo db might prove faster and less needlessly overheady in this scenario. Besides, most CMSs cost money, some of them a lot, while Mongo is free :)

Comment: thanks Andrei.  Im not sure if we want to change the DB. But I could use hibernate if the package allows that.